# Pydrive deleting file from Google Drive

Tags: python, pydrive

I´m writing a small script in python 3.5.2 with pydrive 1.2.1 and I need to be able to delete a file which is not stored locally in my computer, but in my account of Google Drive. The [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#delete-trash-and-un-trash-files) only show how to delete a file you previously created, not one which is already stored on the drive. Is deleting an existing file actually possible with pydrive? if so, how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the docs seems that `drive.CreateFile()` create only a reference to a file, this can be local or remote.
As you can se [here](http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#download-file-content) `drive.CreateFile()` is used to download a remote file.

I believe that something like this should do the job:

```
# Initialize GoogleDriveFile instance with file id.
file1 = drive.CreateFile({'id': <file-id>})

file1.Trash()  # Move file to trash.
file1.UnTrash()  # Move file out of trash.
file1.Delete()  # Permanently delete the file.
```

Comment: Just to confirm `CreateFile()` creates an instance of GoogleDriveFile which can represent an already existing file (i.e. doesn't necessarily create a new file). You can have a look at the source here:
https://github.com/googledrive/PyDrive/blob/d4a00a9d11fb4aca10126552ea1cf434522e4d30/pydrive/drive.py#L19